# AngularJs selecting data conditionally

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJs. I have a json data as below which I am mapping to table and displaying in tabular manner. The json contains an array of vs_array. The vs_array contains two sections categorized by the dc attribute. In the table I have assumed that the first section will contain India as value in the dc and the second section will contain US as value for the dc attribute. Based on the assumption I have my tr and td to iterate through the json. But the order is not guaranteed. 
 How do i select the section based on dc attribute to populate my table and not on the order of the section.

```
{
   "status": "SUCCESS",
   "status_message": "Susscessfully fetched details.",
   "total_records": 6,
   "m_details":
   [
       {
           "p_id": 1017,
           "vs_aray":
           [
               {
                   "p_member": "abs",
                   "address": "sadsadsd",
                   "dc": "India",
                   "availability": "Offline",
                   "state": "Enabled"
               },
               {
                  "p_member": "abs",
                   "address": "sadsadsd",
                   "dc": "US",
                   "availability": "Offline",
                   "state": "Enabled"
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           "p_id": 1017,
           "vs_aray":
           [
            {
                   "p_member": "abs",
                   "address": "sadsadsd",
                   "dc": "US",
                   "availability": "Offline",
                   "state": "Enabled"
               },
               {
                   "p_member": "abs",
                   "address": "sadsadsd",
                   "dc": "India",
                   "availability": "Offline",
                   "state": "Enabled"
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand:

```
<tr ng-repeat="detail in m_details | filter:yourFilterFunction">
    <!-- some code -->
</tr>
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter